# Why did Maul bother fighting Kanan

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In the Star Wars Rebels Season 2 Finale, we find out that Darth Maul is alive, and he helps Ahsoka and Kanan kill the Inquistors, and helps Ezra get a Sith Holocron. He eventually betrays Kanan, blinds him, and attacks Ahsoka. Ahsoka eventually tells Maul that he'll have to fight Kanan before they can continue fighting. Kanan gets up, Maul attacks him, and he manages to beat Maul. My question is, why did Maul attack Kanan, since he was blind, Kanan wouldn't have been able to stop him if he continued after Ahsoka. Maul could have just left Kanan there and continued on to the top of the Sith Temple. There was really no reason for him to fight Kanan, so why did he do it?

Comment: Why did the evil, dangerously unpredictable villain do something villainous and unpredictable?

Comment: It seemed unnecessary for Maul to fight him. If he had been left there by Maul, he would have been killed by the Temple's activation.

Comment: Maul hates the Jedi. It's his defining characteristic and leads him into making terrible choices, like not just blowing Obi-Wan and Qui-Gon into smithereens with a bomb instead of ambushing them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward answer is that he wanted Kanan out of the way so he'd be free to continue to corrupt Ezra to the dark side. If left alive there's a chance he could have interfered with that, even blinded.

On a more personal level, it's clear from his tone that he found the notion of a blind Kanan being any serious physical threat to be amusing. In his eyes, it would have been something of a mercy killing, hence: *"I...(suppressing a chuckle)...will make this quick."*

On an even deeper emotional level, this can all be boiled down to *"because he could and wanted to"*, which is pretty much why any Sith does anything. They're all about self gratification.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not Canon anymore, in Jedi Knight, Jerec (the end boss) was blind.
I does not seems to bother him more than Matt Murdock...

Still canon,  in episode IV, one of the first (easiest ?) training of Luke involve being blinded.
[image: luke training]

I don't think blindness is a big drawback for a Jedi.

Comment: Fill out the details of Luke's blindness training (I assume you mean with the blaster droid) and this could be a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

**It's all about apprentice.**

In last years of his life Maul was broken man (Zabrak actually :) ). He was desperately searching for purpose in life (hope as he defined it). Ezra, as apprentice, was in his mind a way to create his legacy, to create something lasting from his experience and knowledge. Also, as he was alone and going mentally unstable, Ezra's companionship would ease his pain (loss of family , loss of legs, loss of whole clan (Nightsisters and Nightbrothers) and his criminal empire) .

Of course, Kanan was obstacle in his endeavor, because Ezra was currently his Padawan. Also, even before Maul blinded Kanan we see that Kanan didn't trust him much and tried to shield Ezra from his influence. So, for Maul, it was obvious he has to eliminate Kanan to get Ezra for himself ("Ezra will be mine!") .

Now, after blinding Kanan, Ahsoka intervened and prevented Maul from finishing him. Maul did duel Ahshoka but he did not expect that Kanan would recover so fast and use Force to see. Again, Ahshoka was not so important to Maul, because simply she was not Ezra's master. It is very likely he sensed connection between Kanan and Ezra, not between Ahshoka and Ezra. So, when Kanan recovered and Ahshoka run away (sort of), Maul switched back to his primary target but lost.